# Why SDWebImage do not show image in a cell after load?

Tags: ios, uitableview, sdwebimage

I am using SDWebImage. In my table, each row has image and a label.

[image]

As you can see, image cannot be seen.

But when I go back to parent view controller, and come here again, they are shown.

[image]

The code I am using is:

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:serie.image] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]  options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];
```

So, where I am wrong?

Comment: check to see if you have an image named placeholder.png?

Comment: I don't have. But I don't want to use, so I use it nil. But still the same.

Comment: try using a blank placeholder image (transparent png image). That has worked for me.

Comment: That worked. It should be a bug in SDWebImage. Thank you

Comment: this might have been fixed with the following update: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/pull/683

Comment: @Burak see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/34563218/991085

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answer: get/make a transparent png, and use it as your placeholder image.

Actually, it is not a bug with SDWebImage, but rather it's the nature of how UITableView works. SetImageWithURL, is an asynch process. So when your tableView delegate/datasource methods are called, the image isn't downloaded yet, so cellForRow doesn't have an image to display.

The reason it works when you navigate elsewhere then back, is because by then the image has been downloaded, and cellForRow gets called again, this time with an image to display.